Table I/O Select Fetch Next JDE
I am new to JDE and I am working on a form (Find/Browse). What I'm trying to accomplish is to get all the data from my custom table (let's say Fxxxx) and display it in the grid when I press a button, but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Can you help me with this?(i can add thinks or update i just cant display all)
My code:
Fxxxx.Select All;
Fxxxx.Fetch Next;
Instead of 'Next', I do this:
PhoneNumber => GC PhoneNumber;
Name => GC Name;
AddressNumber => GC AddressNumber;
